# Callback function doesn't work when using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

This is the code that I am using, 
When I write the link into the browser (I.E. or Mozilla) it is working like
(MyFunc({"memes":[{"source":"http://www.knall......), 
but when I try to run it as HTML file I have a error in status Bar. 
what is the problem?. Thanks

```
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images"></div>
<script>$.getJSON("http://tagthe.net/api/?url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=MyFunc",function(data){         
               alert(data);
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The error;
In Mozilla       "NULL"  .

In I.E.8         Access denied       line 5113
                 jquery-latest.js

Comment: $.getJSON("http://tagthe.net/api/?url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=?", function(data) { alert(data); } .... please remove the ";" before ", function".

Answer (score 4):

You don't define MyFunc anywhere in your code. You should rather put a `?` in the URL instead of  an arbitrary name, and jQuery will replace it with a generated callback name.

Comment: It's also possible to define a callback for the return JSON object. If the parameters callback and view=json are given the response is encapsulated in a function call to the given callback. So the above request would return MyFunc({"memes" ... }) if the parameter callback=MyFunc was present.

This is the link of API :http://www.tagthe.net/fordevelopers

Comment: @asilloo: Yes, and jQuery has built-in support for this (it's commonly known as "JSONP"). You don't have to define the callback by hand, since jQuery does it for you if you do what I said.

Comment: Martti: as you said I deleted "callback" and changed  the code to
 $.getScript("http://tagthe.net/api/?url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json");

Now I don't have any error but in this case should "alert(data)" work or not because the window is empty. I want to get the data from tagthe.net

Comment: @asilloo: what does ‘work’ mean? What should your code do? The window is empty because there's nothing in your HTML. Also, please read [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: if everything goes ok, you should be getting an alert saying 'object'

Answer (score 0):

Eureka man!
It doesn't work with the latest version... you should use the jquery 1.3.1 not newer...

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `getScript` instead of `getJSON` since you are calling a URL on another domain name.

**Update:**

The following code works fine for me:

```
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images"></div>
    <script>
        function MyFunc(data) {
            alert(data)
        }
        $.getScript("http://tagthe.net/api/?url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=MyFunc");
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Nope. jQuery takes care of this for you.

Comment: The new error;
In Mozilla       "undefined"  .

In I.E.8         Access denied       line 5113
                 jquery-latest.js

Comment: Regarding your update: yes, that's because you provide a solution to the problem pointed out by Matti.

Comment: Oh well, I feel stupid now... I didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: The new error; In Mozilla and I.E.8. they are saying  [object Object]

Comment: @asilloo: Geez, is "the new error" all you can say? That's not an error. That's your code working. Use Firebug and `console.log(data)` for a more useful view into your object.

Comment: @asilloo: First, you should update your original question or ask a new one, instead of commenting on someone's answer when you have another question. The message is correct, because the data you get “will be a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method.” See [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score -1):

**you cant make ajax calls to other domains**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

**Also, your URL is not a valid url, copy and paste it in a browser and you will see an error**
http://tagthe.net/api/url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=MyFunc

your valid URL is:
http://tagthe.net/api/?url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=MyFunc

```
$.getJSON("
    http://tagthe.net/api/url=http://www.knallgrau.at/en&view=json&callback=MyFunc",
    function(data){         
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: 1) JSONP is used to get around the same origin policy and 2) I believe the URL in the original is quite correct. At least it's not missing the "?" you say it is